# How to create a phone tracker in codename one

Tags: codenameone

Pls I Want to develop an app that can track the location of a stolen phone. I was able to fetch  "Country, "Carrier,  "MCC",   "MNC".  In my research is as if I will need  Local Area Code (LAC)- To detect device in which region.
and Cell ID - Unique id of that region. pls how can I go about this? Or can anybody help with the coding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some of that data is available in the `Display` class. However, devices block the access to this information to protect users privacy from spyware. You would need complex permissions & authorization to access that sort of information from a system level.

That means you need to understand native code and even if you do this is impossible to implement on locked down platforms such as iOS.

Comment: Sir, if I can get you very well, this is not possible in iOS. What about android? If it is possible in android, pls how can I get the  Local Area Code and Cell ID in the Display class.

Comment: You can do that with native interfaces but you will need to add some permissions like phone access etc.